# How To Update the cost of a product by using the advanced pricing in import function

Tags: magento2, php, error, csv, advanced-pricing

[image]

How To Update the **cost of a product** by using the **advanced pricing** in import function.

In my csv file if I add the **cost field** it was showing an **error**.